# Calculate align page of an address statically

Tags: c, linux, system, elf, mprotect

i need to calculate statically the address of the first page that contains the text segment of an elf, in order to use `mprotect()` and make the text segment writable.

`Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
..
  [14] .text             PROGBITS        08048380 000380 0002e0 00  AX  0   0 128`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

How about this program, which compiles normally and does not crash.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

extern char __executable_start;
extern char __etext;

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  int pagesize = sysconf (_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
  char *start =
    (char *) (((uintptr_t) & __executable_start) & ~(pagesize - 1));
  char *end =
    (char *) (((uintptr_t) & __etext + pagesize - 1) & ~(pagesize - 1));
  mprotect (start, end - start, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC);
  printf ("Hello world\n");
  void *m = main;
  *((char *) m) = 0;
  exit (0);
}
```

I've used `__executable_start` and `__etext`, but you might be better seeing if you can get these to work, which are at least documented in man pages:

> **NAME**
>
> ```
>   `etext`, `edata`, `end` - end of program segments
> ```
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
>   extern etext;
>   extern edata;
>   extern end;
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> ```
>   The addresses of these symbols indicate the end of various program segments:
>
>   `etext`  This is the first address past the end of the text segment (the program
>            code).
>
>   `edata`  This is the first address past the end of the initialized data segment.
>
>   `end`    This  is the first address past the end of the uninitialized data
>            segment (also known as the BSS segment).
> ```
>
> **CONFORMING TO**
>
> ```
>   Although these symbols have long been provided on most UNIX systems, they are
>   not standardized; use with caution.
> ```